# update data with useState in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I have faced one issue and not able to solve it. I am looking for your help.
I have an array which I have listed below. All data are looped and displayed in the view. From my current array, I want to update the count of dietry array[] which is inside the fruits array.

This is my useState

```
const [foods, setFood] = useState(fruits)
```

if I console.log(foods) it gives data as below.

```
fruits: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Banana',
        family: 'abc',
        price: 2.99,
        isEnabled: true,
        dietary: [
            {
                id:1,
                disabled: false,
                group: null,
                selected: false,
                text: 'N/A',
                value: '858090000',
                count:0
            },
            {  
                id:2,
                disabled: true,
                group: null,
                selected: true,
                text: 'N/A',
                value: '80000',
                count:0
            },
        }
```

This data are looped in a view page and there is onClick handleIncrement method which should increment the count of dietary array of index 0 or index1 etc whichever index sent from handleIncremnt() method.
This is my method

```
const handleIncrementCount = (dietary_index) => {
    setFood(foods =>
        foods.map((food,index) =>
         dietary_index === food[index] ? {...food, qty:food.count+1}:food
        )
    );
}
```

I am not able to increase the count, in my view page counts are 0 even if i click the increment button.It shows some error within map

Any help is highly appreciated

I ma looking for a solutions

Comment: should it be `dietary_id == index ? ...` ?

Comment: yes, it is an index. Thanks